# CreateExport: Failed to load Outer for resource

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am trying to build package in Unreal Engine for Windows 64 Bit but I am getting weird error.

```
  LogPackageName: Error: DoesPackageExist: DoesPackageExist FAILED: '/SunPosition/SunSky' is not a standard unreal filename or a long path name. Reason: Path does not start with a valid root. Path must begin with: '/Engine/', '/Game/', '/Paper2D/', '/AnimationSharing/', '/GeometryMode/', '/SpeedTreeImporter/', '/MagicLeap/', '/ChaosClothEditor/', '/ChaosNiagar
a/', '/ChaosSolverPlugin/', '/MagicLeapPassableWorld/', '/Niagara/', '/GeometryCollectionPlugin/', '/GeometryProcessing/', '/MotoSynth/', '/MediaCompositing/', '/PixelStreaming/', '/AudioSynesthesia/', '/PostSplashScreen/', '/Synthesis/', '/DatasmithContent/', '/OculusVR/', '/SteamVR/', '/PureWeb/', '/Config/', '/Script/', '/Extra/', '/Memory/', or '/Temp/'
```

I tried googling but the solution posted on UE forum didnt fix my issue. I am attaching log files [here](https://pastebin.com/ZTdHskUZ) as well. Tried deleting blueprints, cache in `AppData/Local/UnrealEngine`, Intermediate Folder but nothing helps.